# Get rid of the _id field in a find query in mongoDB + Codeigniter

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

To get rid of the _id field in a find query in mongo, I used this query, it worked exactly fine..

```
db.collection.find({}, {'_id': False})
```

- I need to convert this query to codeigniter understandable format (i am using Alex Bilbe's Library)

**Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated..

Comment: can you try out db.collection.select(array(),array('_id'))??

Comment: yes.. I got it already.. thanks anyways. :)